# Is there a name for the $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in general?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, soft-question

How to call the $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in general? It is cumbersome to say something like $n$ is the number of the folds of $\mathbb{R}$ in the Cartesian product ...

If $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is regarded as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, then the difficulty vanishes because one can simply call $n$ the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: What's wrong with calling it the dimension?

Comment: I am not sure if it is proper to call it "dimension" in every occasion.

Comment: It depends on what you're thinking of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as. If you're thinking of it as a set, then of course the $n$ has no meaning because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in bijection with the real numbers. If you're thinking of it as a vector space or as a manifold it makes perfect sense. So it depends on what situation you're in.

Comment: Thanks. So you are trying to say that there is no general name for it? right?

Comment: Certainly not in the context of sets. If you're a manifold, vector space or even a topological space, the $n$ is well defined. In all those cases, the term "dimension" seems appropriate.

Comment: I would say it's completely okay to call $n$ the number of factors of folds in the cartesian product.

Comment: @Svinepels: Thanks for interest. I just feel that it is a lengthy way and would like to seek after a nicer, more refined nomenclature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $n$ is the **dimension** of $\mathbb R^n$. But sometimes, the single word "dimension" isn't specific enough. If you're writing about things embedded within $\mathbb R^n$ that have their own dimensions $\leq n$, then you can refer to $n$ as the **ambient dimension** or the **top dimension**. A thing with dimension $n$ is then called **top-dimensional**.